# Why does sharing a KeyframesEffect with two Animations cause one animation to never end?

Tags: javascript, web-animations

In the following example, one animation will complete, and the other will keep going (because playState is not equal to finished):

```js
const keyframes = new KeyframeEffect(null, [
    { // from
        opacity: 0,
    },
    { // to
        opacity: 1,
    }
], {duration: 2000, easing: 'ease'})

{
    const anim = new Animation(
        keyframes,
        document.timeline
    )

    anim.play()

    requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
      console.log('1', keyframes.getComputedTiming().progress)
      if (anim.playState != 'finished') requestAnimationFrame(loop)
    }, 100)
}


{
    const anim = new Animation(
        keyframes,
        document.timeline
    )

    anim.play()

    requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
      console.log('2', keyframes.getComputedTiming().progress)
      if (anim.playState != 'finished') requestAnimationFrame(loop)
    }, 100)
}
```

Why does one animation never get "finished"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnimationEffect`s, of which `KeyframeEffect` is a subclass, cannot be shared between `Animation`s. This is because they rely on various state associated with their `Animation`.

(In particular, they need to know if they are associated with a transition / CSS animation in order to stack correctly, and they need to know their animation's playback rate in order produce the right value at the ends of their active interval.)

As a result, if you try to associate an `AnimationEffect` with an `Animation`, it is removed from any `Animation` it was previously associated with. This is specified in the procedure to [set the associated effect of an animation](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations-1/#set-the-associated-effect-of-an-animation).

Incidentally, this is why the `KeyframeEffect` interface has a ["copy constructor"](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations-1/#dom-keyframeeffect-keyframeeffect-source) so that you can clone `KeyframeEffect`s.

So in your example you could address this using:

```
const anim = new Animation(
  new KeyframeEffect(keyframes),
  document.timeline
)
```

Now, as for why one of the animations never finishes, that appears to be a bug in Chrome. In Firefox the first animation (which lost its `AnimationEffect`) will terminate almost immediately after starting because its [associated effect end](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations-1/#associated-effect-end) becomes zero.

Comment: Ah, nice, I didn't know about the copy constructor. That's useful. But this (in my opinion) shows a design that wasn't designed well enough, because the way it works allows users to pass references in a free way that doesn't work. Maybe instead the effect references should be created when an Animation is created (so effects are already associated, and there's no way to pass them to another animation), thus being a more coupled API. Otherwise this looser coupling leaves room for error or confusion.

Comment: That's a fair point. The design comes about largely because Web Animations was initially specified to include nested effects but that was subsequently moved to level 2. Nested effects follow the model of DOM tree manipulation where adding a node as a child of another removes it from its previous parent. This same behavior was applied all the way to the root of the effect tree.